# Can a custom object be passed in a datalayer to google analytics 4

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, data-layers

I want to create an event in Google Analytics 4 which has an object as value. How can we achieve this .

DataLayer format :

```
dataLayer.push({
      'event': 'test_event',
      'prod': {
        'item_name': 'test',
        'item_id': '67891',
        'item_price': '100',
        'item_category': 'Electronics',
        'item_quantity': '2'
      }
    })
```

In GA4 getting the value of event 'test_event' as [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reference for event field types: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/ga4/reference

Make sure you're setting the correct field that actually expects an object rather than a string.

You're not sending GA4 events just by setting the dataLayer. You're meant to have GTM logic to parse through the DL and convert DL pushes into actual network requests. I don't see you mentioning the GTM-side implementation, so have to indicate it just in case.

Also, note that GA4 is a raw product at the moment, despite Google is trying to promote it. It's not yet considered to be a good idea to rely on it. It is, however, a good idea to start having parallel tracking in GA4 just in case Google decides to completely deprecate the Universal Analytics.